# Site name cut off in advertisement

Tags: bug, status-declined, advertising

Here is a screenshot that should pretty much explain everything:

[image]

Kind of looks unprofessional when part of it is cut off.

Comment: Freehand circles > freehand arrows. Also, string overflow!!!

Comment: @Bolt: Circles are now depreciated in favor of arrows.

Comment: deprecated⁠⁠⁠⁠⁠

Comment: @Gnome: Ah, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends what fonts you have.

Ubuntu is known for EXTREMELY wide fonts.

[Slight rendering bug in Chrome (Linux) - View count and title overlap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33090/slight-rendering-bug-in-chrome-linux-view-count-and-title-overlap/33110#33110)

Comment: A workaround might be to render the text as an image - but that's absurd. I guess we'll just have to accept it.

Comment: Ubuntu now uses a much thinner font with the release of 10.10

Answer (score 4):

I just hit upon this on a boardgames.stackexchange ad:

[image: Board Games Advertisement getting cut off]

The problem is not that Ubuntu and other Linux distros uses extra wide fonts (I myself installed `ttf-mscorefont`, so it shouldn't be a problem), but rather that the ad specifies `Arial Narrow`, which most non-Windows users do not have. I think advertisement *should* be reviewed to avoid this - the number of non-Windows users [certainly isn't insignificant](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-2010-analytics/).