# Add button for adding favourite / ignored tag slightly cut off

Tags: bug, ignored-tags, design, tag-watching

See the following screen-shot:

[image]

That's Firefox 5 on Ubuntu 11.04. It could be that I don't have the intended font and may be falling back to one that has different character widths?

Specified font family: `Trebuchet MS,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif`. It appears to be attempting to use Liberation Sans. When I remove that using firebug, it gets even worse (presumably because it uses the even wider OS default).

Ubuntu doesn't appear to be doing any sneaky swapping of fonts:

```
>fc-match "Liberation Sans"
LiberationSans-Regular.ttf: "Liberation Sans" "Regular"
```

Not a huge problem, but I thought I ought to point it out.

Comment: related to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33090/slight-rendering-bug-in-chrome-linux-view-count-and-title-overlap/33110#33110 -- there are font substitutions on Ubuntu that are VERY VERY WIDE

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. Yes, it would appear so... However, the altered font CSS appears to not have solved it. I can see that the font-family specified is `Trebuchet MS,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;`, which is what you thought should fix the issue in the other question, but it hasn't. I'll dig around and see if I can find out what font it's actually using.

Comment: @Jeff, I have updated the question with some details of the font being used.

Comment: What? You mean not everyone has Trebuchet MS?!

Comment: ive got Firefox 18 on Win7 and the same bug.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its only caused by the font,
Ive got the same error on 2 diffrent Windows-computer with 2 diffrent browsers and both got the standard fonts.
For me i solved this problem temporarily with adding 10 px width to the content and sidebar div via greasemonkey script.
Or you could change the padding of the Add button to: `padding: 0.3em 0.2em;`
so its not that widt that it gets cut off.