# Red box on election page is at the far end of the page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

The red box explaining the rules on the election page is at the bottom end of the page. It's not easy to notice that the text in the box changes depending on the active tab because it is so far away.

There had been a report by someone that he sees the box on the right side which makes a lot more sense.[image]

Comment: no-repro. What browser and platform?

Comment: Firefox 6.0.2 on Ubuntu

Comment: probably a font width issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33090/slight-rendering-bug-in-chrome-linux-view-count-and-title-overlap/33110#33110

Comment: Could not reproduce on Ubuntu 10.10 with Firefox 3.6.22, Firefox 6.0.2 and Chromium 12.0.742.112. The red box is on the right side.

Comment: Replicated on Ubuntu 11.04 and Firefox, ONLY when I increase the Zoom of the page. When I reset Zoom it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to reproduce this in a supported version of Firefox.