# These numbers are too crowded! Can we give them some breathing room?

Tags: bug, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slight rendering bug in Chrome (Linux) - View count and title overlap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33090/slight-rendering-bug-in-chrome-linux-view-count-and-title-overlap)

I recently observed the following on the home page of Meta:

[image]

*(Emphasis mine)*

As you can see, the numbers are too crowded together and should really be spaced out more to prevent overlap. The question in question (hmm, that sounded awkward) is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed).

Comment: Also... is the [Eeeek! meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83625/142114) still in? I wasn't sure what to prefix my question with :)

Comment: It's supposed to abbreviate over 1,000 views as just 1k views... and turn it an orange-ish tint color.

Comment: The views should never display like that...was that manually edited?

Comment: Isn't a question with fewer than -99 votes a bit edge case-ish?

Comment: @NickCraver: No - that was a screenshot of the page.

Comment: The question shouldn't have shown up in the first place, given its -102 votes. Weird stuff.

Comment: Frankly, what really surprised me is that a question with over 100 downvotes made it to the home page.

Comment: Your ellipse is very suspicious sir.

Comment: @TimStone So it *does* hide low scoring questions from the front page?  I had suspected...

Comment: Also, @GeorgeEdison, "Eeeek" is *always* in.

Comment: @BobCratchit: I don't get it... the question showed up on the home page... that would suggest a bug?

Comment: That's what I'm asking Tim. :P The view count is definitely a bug though...should've displayed as "2k".

Comment: Would it pop back up on the home page because he added (and keeps adding) another +500 bounty to the question?

Comment: [In the featured list](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured) the same thing gets more space. [Not too nice either](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KoB4D.png) ;-)

Comment: @animuson, it seems like that, but that is odd too, considering [Why is the question with the newest bounty, with score < -100, not in the featured tab?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116148/why-is-the-question-with-the-newest-bounty-with-score-100-not-in-the-featur)

Comment: @Bob, as for hiding posts: see Jeff's **(old)** answer to [Meta sites' front pages should not hide questions with very low scores](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62729/meta-sites-front-pages-should-not-hide-questions-with-very-low-scores/62769#62769).

Comment: @nick see dupe I closed of-- same exact issue. has to do with fonts on the user's platform.

Comment: @Jeff - ahh there it is, I swore I saw this before but couldn't find the linux question, thanks!

Comment: Just to be sure, @Jeff and Nick, for the featured list the same **(minor)** issue on a fresh OS X Lion install, in both [Safari](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kHUfv.png) and [Chrome](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KoB4D.png). [Firefox](http://i.stack.imgur.com/00vNP.png) is okay indeed. I doubt it's only *font* related then?

Comment: (@Nick, ping for my above comment.)

Comment: @JeffAtwood: I'm not using Linux ATM :) I'm using Windows 8.

Comment: @george we don't support beta OSes or beta browsers. If it persists with the final retail version of the OS feel free to ask again.